# Google Sheets - Merging stacked columns

Tags: graph, google-sheets

I'm trying to provide a visualisation for a sales funnel in Google Sheets, but combine columns 2 and 3 (disqualifications), then 4 and 5 (successful leads) so that it stacks them. Anyone know if this is possible?

[image: Example chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting up two series (where the first data item in the second series has the value zero):

[image]

You can also add data labels like this

[image]